# Python module issue

Tags: python, linux, mysql-python, bluehost

I have a shared hosting environment on Bluehost. I am running a custom installation of python(+ django) with a few installed modules. All has been working, until yesterday a change was made on the server(I assume) which gave me this django error:

```
... File "/****/****/.local/lib/python/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)

File "/****/****/.local/lib/python/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 14, in 
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)

ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Of course, Bluehost support is not too helpful. They advised that 1) I use the default python install, because that has MySQLdb installed already. Or that 2) I somehow import the MySQLdb package installed on the default python, from my python(dont know if this can even be done). I am concerned that if I use the default install I wont have permission to install my other packages.

Does anybody have any ideas how to get back to a working state, with as little infrastructure changes as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you upgraded your OS installation which in turn upgraded `libmysqlclient` and broke native extension. What you can do is reinstall `libmysqlclient16` again (how to do it depends your particular OS) and that should fix your issue.

Other approach would be to uninstall `MySQLdb` module and reinstall it again, forcing python to compile it against a newer library.

Answer (score 0):

You were right. Bluehost upgraded MySQL. Here is what I did:
1) remove the "build" directory in the "MySQL-python-1.2.3" directory
2) remove the egg
3) build the module again "python setup.py build"
4) install the module again "python setup.py install --prefix=$HOME/.local"

Morale of the story for me is to remove the old stuff when reinstalling module