# locate libmysqlclient_r.so.16 issue

Tags: python, django, linux, mysql-python

Like to start off by advising that i am a novice and my webdesigner is out of the country. I have the issue below and looking for some advice. I have already re-installed mysqldb and upgraded the packages. I talked to my hosting company and they advised they upgraded to mysql 5.5.

I searched the web and stackoverflow and tried many different solutions as mentioned above.

This is the error from the error log on the server:

```
    [Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/flup-1.0.3.dev_20110405-py2.5.egg/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 574, in run
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:     protocolStatus, appStatus = self.server.handler(self)
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/flup-1.0.3.dev_20110405-py2.5.egg/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 1159, in handler
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:     result = self.application(environ, start_response)
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 194, in __call__
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:     self.load_middleware()
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 38, in load_middleware
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:     mod = __import__(mw_module, {}, {}, [''])
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/flatpages/middleware.py", line 1, in 
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:     from django.contrib.flatpages.views import flatpage
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/flatpages/views.py", line 1, in 
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:     from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/flatpages/models.py", line 2, in 
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:     from django.db import models
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 17, in 
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:     backend = __import__('%s%s.base' % (_import_path, settings.DATABASE_ENGINE), {}, {}, [''])
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 12, in 
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr:     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
[Wed Dec 05 12:12:47 2012] [warn] [client 146.145.36.41] mod_fcgid: stderr: ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here is the  same error again but via python:

python jdm_cars.fcgi

```
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
/home1/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/MySQL_python_embedded-1.2.3-py2.5-linux-x86_64.egg/_mysql.py:3: UserWarning: Module _mysql was already imported from /home1/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/MySQL_python_embedded-1.2.3-py2.5-linux-x86_64.egg/_mysql.py, but /home1/elitejdm/public_html/new_elitejdm/MySQL-python-1.2.3 is being added to sys.path
  import sys, pkg_resources, imp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home1/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/flup-1.0.3.dev_20110405-py2.5.egg/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 574, in run
    protocolStatus, appStatus = self.server.handler(self)
  File "/home1/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/flup-1.0.3.dev_20110405-py2.5.egg/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 1159, in handler
    result = self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 194, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 38, in load_middleware
    mod = __import__(mw_module, {}, {}, [''])
  File "/home/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/flatpages/middleware.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.flatpages.views import flatpage
  File "/home/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/flatpages/views.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
  File "/home/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/flatpages/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/home/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    backend = __import__('%s%s.base' % (_import_path, settings.DATABASE_ENGINE), {}, {}, [''])
  File "/home/elitejdm/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>Unhandled Exception</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unhandled Exception</h1>
<p>An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.</p>
</body></html>
```

while wirting this i found out more info from my hosting company  i was told the follwing

Basicly we updated libmysqlclient to: 
libmysqlclient_r.so.18

From:
libmysqlclient_r.so.16

> Due to being in a shared hosting environment, we have to make these
>   updates from time to time. It appears this is what is causing you
>   grief/issue.
>
> You'll either A need to reinstall libmysqlclient_r.so.16 locally on
>   your server without root access. (without yum)
>
> OR B configure your script to handle the new .18 version.
>
> If you do the first way, you won't need to update it in the future. If
>   you do it the second way and we decide to update again. It will
>   require you to update your scripts again

Pretty new to this so i am not sure how to do either but willing to learn... please any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you let us know what distribution you're running, and how django was installed?

Comment: I am not sure how django was installed. I am not the designer. He is on vacation. As for the version here you go! Linux version 2.6.32-20120131.55.1.bh6.x86_64 (machbuild@build6.bluehost.com) (gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Jan 31 15:43:27 EST 2012

Comment: As for django are you refering to easy_install?

Answer (score -1):

[Python module issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573359/python-module-issue)

Please check out the second answer on this thread. Fixed my issue.